# Получить первый кадр видео

Tags: javascript

Нужно получить первый кадр из видео и вставить в img на javascripte

Comment: Запустите видео и БЫСТРО нажмите кнопку PrintScreen. Потом в Paint вырежьте картинку вот Вам и первый кадр. :-) А если серьезно, то есть куча видеоредакторов, в том числе бесплатных и онлайн, которые позволяют вырезать любой кадр.

Comment: спасибо, но это все нужно делать на javascripte)

Comment: А, пиратский сайт для видео пишете? Тогда надо искать либу на  javascript для работы с видео. :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699721/javascript-extract-video-frames-reliably

Answer (score 2):

Взято с https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749011/capture-first-frame-of-an-embedded-video

```
// Create a video element.
var vid = document.createElement("video");

// We don't want it to start playing yet.
vid.autoplay = false;
vid.loop = false;

// No need for user to see the video itself.
vid.style.display = "none";

// This will fire when there's some data loaded for the video, should be at least 1 frame here.
vid.addEventListener("loadeddata", function()
{
    // Let's wait another 100ms just in case?
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        // Create a canvas element, this is what user sees.
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

        // Set it to same dimensions as video.
        canvas.width = vid.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = vid.videoHeight;

        // Put it on page.
        document.getElementById("done").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("done").appendChild(canvas);

        // Get the drawing context for canvas.
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // Draw the current frame of video onto canvas.
        ctx.drawImage(vid, 0, 0);

        // Done!
    });
}, false);

// Have to include .ogv for firefox. I don't think this is working atm because my webserver isn't serving up
// videos properly.
if(BrowserDetect.browser == "Firefox")
{
var source = document.createElement("source");
source.src = "BigBuckBunny_640x360.ogv";
source.type = "video/ogg";
vid.appendChild(source);
}
else
{
var source = document.createElement("source");
source.src = "BigBuckBunny_640x360.mp4";
source.type = "video/mp4";
vid.appendChild(source);
}

// Add video to document to start loading process now.
document.body.appendChild(vid);
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если это решение Вашего вопроса, то отметьте его как правильный, чтобы остальные участники могли его использовать.